# useState not reading variable outside of if statement

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, use-state

I'm trying to set a variable "list" in an "if" statement, and after that, update my data via useState, but if I write setData outside the "if" statement, it shows that the variable "list" is not defined, so I must rewrite all the code inside the "if" and the "else" statement (which is not desirable)

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  name: "",
  email: "",
  machinetype: [],
});

const handleInputChange = (event) => {
  if (event.target.name === "machinetype") {
    const chck = event.target.checked;
    if (chck) {
      const list = data[event.target.name].concat([event.target.value]);
    } else {
      const index = data[event.target.name].indexOf(event.target.value);
      const remove = data[event.target.name].splice(index, 1);
      const list = data[event.target.name];
    }
    setData({
      ...data,
      [event.target.name]: list,
    });
  }
};
```

Any advices? Thanks

Comment: Const variables are scoped to their immediate surrounding { } curly braces and can’t be accessed in an outer lexical scope. Define the variable above the if block with ‘let’ instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variables declared within if statements stay within the scope of the if statement. So when the pointer leaves the if block the variable is disposed of.

all you need to do is the following

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  name: "",
  email: "",
  machinetype: [],
});

const handleInputChange = (event) => {
  if (event.target.name === "machinetype") {
    const chck = event.target.checked;
    let list = null;
    if (chck) {
      list = data[event.target.name].concat([event.target.value]);
    } else {
      const index = data[event.target.name].indexOf(event.target.value);
      const remove = data[event.target.name].splice(index, 1);
      list = data[event.target.name];
    }
    setData({
      ...data,
      [event.target.name]: list,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of `list` outside the ifs.

You'll also want to make sure you're not internally modifying the list without copying it, so all in all something like

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  name: "",
  email: "",
  machinetype: [],
});

const handleInputChange = (event) => {
  const {name} = event.target;
  if (name !== "machinetype") {  // early return to make the function shallower
    return;
  }
  const list = [...data[name]]; // shallow copy
  if (event.target.checked) {
    list.push(event.target.value);
  } else {
    const index = list.indexOf(event.target.value);
    list.splice(index, 1);
  }
  setData({
    ...data,
    [name]: list,
  });
};
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

While you can declare `list` ahead of time with `let`...

```
if (event.target.name === "machinetype"){
  const chck = event.target.checked
  let list;
  // assign to list...
```

A nicer approach IMO would be to consolidate the two possibilities into a single expression.

```
if (!chck) {
    // this block doesn't make much sense though
    const index = data[event.target.name].indexOf(event.target.value);
    const remove = data[event.target.name].splice(index, 1);
}
const list = data[event.target.name].concat(chck ? [event.target.value] : []);
setData({
  ...data,
  [event.target.name]: list,
});
```

But the assignment to unused variable `remove` doesn't make sense, and mutation should never be done to state in React. Better to do something like

```
const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { name, value, checked } = target;
    if (name !== "machinetype") return;
    if (checked) {
        setData({
            ...data,
            [name]: [...data[name], value],
        });
    } else {
        setData({
            ...data,
            [name]: data[name].filter(existingVal => existingVal !== value)
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: That's missing the whole `.splice()` thing to remove things from the list though.